# How does dynamic control light works

Tags: nissan, car, diy, dashboard

Take the example from Nissan Juke dashboard: There are 2 modes in the dashboard, the first mode is when the label shows "A/C" and in the other mode, it shows the  label "Normal". I was wondering how the label changes on the same space and how it works. See below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're asking. Could you elaborate?

Comment: updated the question with images

Comment: It's still not clear what you are asking.  I assume both of these images were taken in a different car because the buttons that surround the display are clearly different (i.e. A/C, Off, Windows and Feet in image 1, Normal, Sport and Eco in image 2).

Comment: Are you asking about the button changing the label? My guess that if the buttons changes labels while using is that they have tiny displays behind them. Just like those fancy computer keyboards for gamers where each button has a 48x48 OLED display integrated (*Optimus Maximus*).

Comment: the cars might be different, but A/C Normal are present in both cars, press a button and it alters. @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing thats a good start, will search more

Comment: Look at the eco button in the lower left in the bottom picture, you can clearly see the outline of the screen demist/foot heater icon from the same position in the top image.

Comment: can you provide more info on the screen, if it is a screen?

Comment: @HishamMaudarbocus What do you mean "more info"? It's a tiny screen. You can find info on OLED/LCD tech on Wikipedia or elsewhere. You can see the little screens pretty clearly in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOuQtD0kTBU as well. If you want some real fun check out the Tesla Model S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As IHaveNoIdeaWhatI'mDoing stated in the comments, the buttons themselves have small LCD or OLED screens that allow them to change depending on some set of predetermined conditions. i.e. when the a/c is on, the button displays 'normal', and pressing it turns the a/c off, and when the a/c is off the button displays 'a/c' and pressing it turns the a/c on.